# Can't map uiLabelMap when i replaced label file with new file in config directory of OFBiz

Tags: java, ofbiz

I'm new in `OFBiz`, every thing was working properly, `uiLabel` was mapped and it was working properly, but when i replaced the `uiLabel` file with new file problem occur (i restrart server (`ant build`, and `ant start`), but `uiLabel` is not working). So how i can solve that? thanks for any guide and help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have used the same file name as your previous working `uiLabel`? Do you have validated your uiLabel file, e.g. under Eclipse `'right click - validate`? Maybe your `uiLabel`is not well formed.

Please give us some more information what "is not working" means in your case.